# How to count the selected categories or converting the selected categories into a string array

Tags: gwt

since I am not able to post an image. I'll just type the row for the categories. So here is it:
Categories

1-4-5-10-13-27-28-29-34-35-36-51-58-59-60-61-150

1-4-5-10-13-27-28-29-32-34-35-36-51-58-150

this categories are displayed in a grid

i would like to count how many categories where selected by the user. How would that be possible. 
I am doing this because I want the selected categories to be in the selected side in the DualListField

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the selection model either from the fromView or the toView. Then retrieve the selected items from this model.